# RecyclerView not displaying infomation from firebase database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview is not displaying any information. The recyclerview is working fine but the there is no information, it is completely blank. Also the layout is blank...

There is no error in the logcat...

I have tried doing the following:

1] set height in the xml to wrap content.

2] set a notifySetChangeListener.

3] implement startListening.

these were majority of the answers of the same question asked by other people, but even after already implementing all of it, the recyclerView is still blank.

My MainActivity:

```
          @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_users_post_list);
    postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

     DisplayAllUsersProfile();}


      private void DisplayAllUsersProfile() {

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<postsRecyclerView> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<postsRecyclerView>()
                    .setQuery(PostsRef  , postsRecyclerView.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<postsRecyclerView,PostsViewHolder>
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<postsRecyclerView, PostsViewHolder>(options) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
            PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull postsRecyclerView model) {

            holder.textUsername.setText(model.getUsername());
            holder.textContent.setText(model.getContent());
            holder.textTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
            holder.textDate.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.textTime.setText(model.getTimestamp());

            holder.LikePostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    LikeChecker  =  true;
                    LikesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
    postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



public class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textUsername, textTitle, textContent, textDate, textTime;
    TextView DisplayNoOfLikes;
    ImageButton LikePostButton, CommentPostButton;

    public PostsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        LikePostButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
        CommentPostButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_button);
        DisplayNoOfLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_no_of_likes);

        textUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
        textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        textContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_article);
        textDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        textTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
    }
}
```

My model class:

```
      public class postsRecyclerView  {

String username;
String content;
String title;
String date;
String timestamp;

public postsRecyclerView(String username, String content, String title, String date, String timestamp) {
    this.username = username;
    this.content = content;
    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public postsRecyclerView() {
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

My firebase database:
[image: Firebase database]

I really need your help...

I've stuck here for days...

Thanks......

Comment: Do you get any messages/errors in logcat?

Comment: ...And can you post an example of your database structure?

Comment: earlier i didnt get an error but now I am getting one..

Comment: One more question :), is "Notes" node the place where you are storing posts?

Comment: Yes. "Notes" is where im saving posts and PostsRef is         PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes");

Comment: Well; I think what happens then is that you get the direct children of "Notes", which are not what you want in your case; You want CHILDREN of Notes children...

Comment: So could you inform me about what should i write in my code?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

Comment: This was the only method i used before, but then in few question it was written to change 'this' yo getApplicationContext', but it didnt work in both ways

Comment: is onBindViewHolder method is called?

Answer (score 0):

To get it running you can try this solution:

```
PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child("..."); 
// ... is for those Ids of notes
```

Also I think that `startListening()` should be before `setAdapter(...)`

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you... But using this method the error is now gone but The recyclerview is stillblank..